# How to efficiently delete Multiple Session Keys in Java?

Tags: java, session

I am trying to optimize below code snippet. I want to clear multiple session keys in java by using a single loop. So the requirement is that I don't want to clear all the session keys, I want to keep some of the session keys. For example, in below code snippet, I am trying to remove keys containing `ID_NAME_`  and keep the one with the id passed to the method.

Below is the code snippet I wrote which works fine:

```
private void clearPreviousIdFromSession(HttpServletRequest request, String id) {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Enumeration keys = session.getAttributeNames();
        ArrayList<String> keyArrs = new ArrayList<>();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Keys for session : " + key);

            if (key.contains("ID_NAME_"+id)) {
                continue;
            } else if(key.contains("ID_NAME_")) {

                keyArrs.add(key);

            }
        }

        for(String k : keyArrs){
            System.out.println(k);
            session.setAttribute(k, null);
            session.removeAttribute(k);
        }

    }
```

Below is the code I was trying to make it into a single loop, but getting an error because `removeAttribute()` will remove the object bound with the specified name from this session. In this case, I think `key` will be removed and won't be able to check for the nextElement in the list.

```
private void clearPreviousIdFromSession(HttpServletRequest request, String id) {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Enumeration keys = session.getAttributeNames();
        //ArrayList<String> keyArrs = new ArrayList<>();
        String key;
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {

            key = (String) keys.nextElement();

            System.out.println("Keys for session : " + key);

            if (key.contains("ID_NAME_" + id)) {
                continue;
            } else if (key.contains("ID_NAME_")) {

                session.removeAttribute(key);

            }

        }

    }
```

Any suggestions to improve my code. I have tried looking [here](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/SessionMap.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) and some old questions of stack overflow questions and [here](https://www.convertigo.com/Forums/topic/remove-all-sessions-variables/), but still having difficulty. TIA

Comment: Can "ID_NAME_" or "ID_REPO_" really appear anywhere in the string? If they can only appear at the beginning you should be using `startsWith` instead of `contains`, both for performance (minor) and so you don't get a bad surprise someday (!). Also, why do you call your list `keyArrs`? Are you a pirate? I would just call it `keys`.

Comment: Yes @DavidConrad, "ID_NAME" appears at the start of the string. I can use startsWith. Thanks for pointing that out. Also, I don't need to use `keyArrs` for the second solution. I am already using `keys` for enumeration in the first solution. I realize I should have used a better naming convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your want to optimize something that is already well designed.
As you should not remove elements during iteration of them, you collect elements to delete into a List and after iteration you iterate on this List to delete them.
This approach is nice and the logic flow is "optimized".

If you had to really change something in the actual code, it could be the redundant operation :

```
session.setAttribute(k, null);
session.removeAttribute(k);
```

You should choose only one of them  :

```
for(String k : keyArrs){
    System.out.println(k);
    session.removeAttribute(k);
}
```

since `session.setAttribute(k, null)` has the same effect as calling `session.removeAttribute(k)`.

Comment: Thanks david for pointing  out `session.setAttribute(k, null)`, yes I can remove that. But I was thinking if I could do both(iterating and removing) at the same time.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't think as `Enumeration` class is not designed to remove element during iteration as `Iterator` does.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (key.contains("ID_REPO_" + id)) {
                continue;
            } else if (key.contains("ID_REPO_")) {

                session.removeAttribute(key);

            }
```

refactoring this to java stream:

```
key.stream()
.filter(key -> !key.contains("ID_REPO_" + id)) //filter all keys that do not have string
.forEach(key -> session.removeAttribute(key)) // execute lambda on every key filtered
```

Comment: Your solution looks good to me. Only thing I am using Java 7. Will I be able to use this in 7?